# static_cast on shared_ptr leads to undefined behaviour

Tags: c++

According to the book: `The C++ Standard Library: a tutorial and reference` I quote the following:

> The cast operators allow casting a pointer to a different type. The semantic is the same as the corresponding operators, and the result is another shared pointer of a different type. Note that using the ordinary cast operators is not possible, because it results in undefined behavior

So, for instance, the following code produces undefined behaviour:

```
shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr (new Derived);
shared_ptr<Derived>(static_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr.get())); --> Undefined Behaviour.
```

Therefore, `static_pointer_cast()` should be used instead.

Second example:

```
shared_ptr<void> sp(new int);                // shared pointer holds a void* internally
shared_ptr<int>(static_cast<int*>(sp.get())) // ERROR: undefined behavior
```

Is such a a claim indeed supported by the standard ?

Comment: I'm not sure off the top of my head if the cast itself is UB; quite possibly. Actually using the pointer produced by the cast is definitely UB, since `base_ptr.get()` doesn't actually point to an instance of `Derived`.

Comment: Please provide a more complete example - merely casting `Base*` to `Derived*` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Olipro I think its self explanatory, does the result (if actually used) produced by the cast leads to UB?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I am talking about the cast and the result produced by the cast(e.g using it)

Comment: For starters, `base_ptr` holds a pointer to `Base`, **not** a pointer to `Derived`. A `Base` is an incomplete `Derived`. At the very least you need to change the code so `base_ptr` is initialized with a `new Derived`.

Comment: Assuming that you actually meant `shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr (new Derived);` I suspect the book may be talking about `shared_ptr<Derived> derived_ptr(std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_ptr));` vs `shared_ptr<Derived> derived_ptr(static_cast<Derived*>(base_ptr.get()));` The former makes `base_ptr` and `derived_ptr` share the same object. The latter makes each of them believe that they have sole ownership of the object. This is not UB by itself, but it quite likely will lead to UB via double destruction eventually.

Comment: @Cornstalks Why is a `Base` an incomplete `Derived` ? That's an assumption. Moreover, I am asking about the cast not the relationship between the parent and the derived class.

Comment: The names imply that `Derived` inherits from `Base`. If that's true, then `Base` is an incomplete `Derived`. If that's false, then you've chosen very misleading names and omitted important details in your question.

Comment: @Cornstalks yes my bad there, let me edit the question I will also provide a second example

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes you are right, I was downcasting. Let me edit the question I will add one more example.

Comment: Your (updated) first example, as written, doesn't produce UB. But it doesn't actually demonstrate anything interesting; for one thing, it never uses `derived_ptr`. It's just basically `Base* b = new Derived; static_cast<Derived*>(b);` This is fine.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik using that result though wouldn't produce UB? The second example is the exact used in the book. The guy who wrote the book was in the standard committee. That's why I have asked the question in the first place.

Comment: Ah wait, you've updated the example yet again. Now it's UB. It's hard to keep up as you keep changing the question.

Comment: Thank you all for the help/feedback/answers. The example used in the book was miss leading. At least now, I understand what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
shared_ptr<Base> base_ptr (new Derived);  // ** see below
shared_ptr<Derived> derived_ptr;
```

The expression:

```
Derived* p = static_cast<Derived *>(base_ptr.get());
```

Correctly yields a pointer to the derived class interface from the base class pointer. However, this is a raw pointer.

This in of itself is not UB.

However, the next logical mistake might be:

```
derived_ptr.reset(p);
```

This would create a subtle and nasty bug because you'd now have two distinct `shared_ptr`s each with its own control block (the means by which it keeps track of the controlled object's lifetime).

`derived_ptr` and `base_ptr` would now be independently controlling the lifetime of the object pointer to by `p`.

In contrast,

```
derived_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(base_ptr);
```

causes `derived_ptr` to share the same control block as `base_ptr`, and as a result, the lifetime of the new object would be correctly managed.

Note that you have UB in any case in the stated example.

You can only `static_cast` to `Derived` if `base_ptr` **really is** pointing to a `Derived`. In your case it's not. It's pointing to a `Base` and no amount of casting will downcast it correctly.

I have made the edit to correct this, above.

Comment: @RichardHodged Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `static_cast` on shared pointers. This is wrong because you have to transfer the deleter information too. Use [`std::static_pointer_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

```
std::shared_ptr<int> int_ptr = std::static_pointer_cast<int>(sp);
```

What you're doing will create a new `shared_ptr` object with a new reference counter. When both `shared_ptr` objects go out of scope, both will try to delete the same pointer, which will lead to a segfault.

Comment: so the deleter is no transferred? If the deleter is the default, why wouldn't a `static_cast` suffice ?

Comment: @KostasRim Because both `shared_ptr` objects will try to delete the same pointer when they go out of scope. You want to increase the same reference counter, not create a new one.

Comment: Thank your for the answer. The ownership now belong into two different shared_ptr<>. Therefore, UB, due to double deletion (after they go out of scope). I got it!

Answer (score 1):

Shared pointers are two things; pointers to data, and pointers to control blocks.

When you explicitly convert a pointer to data to a shared ptr, you cause it to allocate a new control block.

If the same poimter is controlled by 2 control blocks, both deleters will be called when they go out of scope.  The default deleter deletes the pointer, and doing that twice *is* undefined behaviour.

But nothinf goes wrong *immediately*.

Here we have an alternative approach that doesn't use static pointer cast:

```
shared_ptr<void> sp(new int);                // shared pointer holds a void* internally
shared_ptr<int>(sp, static_cast<int*>(sp.get())) //OK: aliasing constructor
```

the "aliasing" constructor of `shared_ptr` lets you pass a separate control block and data pointer.  The control block is represented by another shared ptr (from which is adds a reference and gets the control block) of *any* type.

Comment: `the aliasing constructor` was mentioned in the book. The concept is now clear to me. Thank you!